# How to randomly pick up to n levels of a factor and then subset the dataframe based on those n levels in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe where the rows are my sample IDs and I would like to randomly pick up to nrows within each level of a factor Y. What I mean by that is that not all levels have the same sample number so if level X gets chosen and it only has 3 samples and n was equal to 10, then the script would pick up all three samples (or rows in this case). If level Z gets chosen and it has 30 samples, then 10 samples will randomly be selected.

So basically a script that randomly picks n rows from each level of Factor Y and for levels with less than n rows, all rows are selected. If you have suggestions on how to do this in Pandas that would be even better.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a count column that counts within each Factor, Level combo, then scramble it. We then query for the relevant factor and grab any with a count lower than or equal to our desired sample size.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({ 'ID': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
                    'Level': ['X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z'],
                    'Factor': ['Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y']})

df['Count'] = 1
df['Count'] = df.groupby(['Factor', 'Level'])['Count'].cumsum()
df['Count'] = df.groupby(['Factor', 'Level'])['Count'].sample(frac = 1).values

sample = df.loc[(df['Factor'] == 'Y') & (df['Count'] <= 5)]
```

Comment: THank you! So I am guessing I can't use the normal "sample" function in pandas because this wouldn't allow the choosing "up to" a certain number?

Comment: Yes, an attempt to use `groupby.sample` will break if the sample size is greater than any of the group sizes.